# relocation error and no version information available when running ffmpeg

Tags: linux, nginx, ffmpeg, rtmp, nvidia-jetson

When ffmpeg is executed, a relocation error and no version information available appears.
The device is Jetsonano and the environment is Ubuntu 18.04 and the camera is using picam2.
I installed gcc version 6,7,8,9,11 and tried to run it, but I keep getting the same error

I saw this and try it
https://github.com/DeTeam/webcam-stream/blob/master/Tutorial.md

ffmpeg

ffmpeg:  /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcdio.so.17 : no version information available (required by /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcdio_paranoia.so.2)

ffmpeg:  /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcdio.so.17 : no version information available (required by /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcdio_cdda.so.2)

ffmpeg: relocation error : /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcdio_paranoia.so.2: symbolcdio_os_driver version CDIO_17 not defined in file libcdio.so.17 with link time reference

thanks